# Aptly: Can I auto-update local mirrors?

Tags: debian

I've set up Aptly to mirror an external repo on the Internet. With Aptly, as far as I can tell, the workflow for updating the local mirror with update packages published on the external repo, is something like this:

1. Update the mirror
2. Create a snapshot
3. Publish the snapshot

In my case, I'd like a workflow like this:

1. The mirror per default is automatically updated (i.e. automatically pulling in updates from the repo on the internet), and these updates are immediately available to our internal non-production  linux servers
2. Before upgrading production servers, we freeze the mirror (by creating snapshots), upgrade our test-servers, and the update production.

Have other Aptly users got a workflow like this up and running? 
I'm thinking it would be possible to create a shell script that pull in new updated say daily, create a snapshot and publishes it, but I'm hoping there is a better way to use Aptly for my desired workflow.